# Приложение крашится с Local reference table overflow(max=512) (Unity 5.6.2f1)

Tags: android, unity3d

Дебаг через adb logcat c фильтром Unity не дал ничего.Добавив Activity и Package Manager было получено "process died" и всё. Но ситуацию спас MiLog который и просветил ситуацию.
На форуме один из возможных вариантов решения было убрать **"Multithreading rendering"** в PlayerSettings, но это не помогло. Думал проблема в том что я использую слишком много локальных переменных в методе. Но причина было не совсем в переменных. Для построения карты 50х50, в некоторых клетках есть изображение которое мне нужно загрузить с сервера и таковых примерно ~500. Для загрузки я использовал корутину с **WWW** классом и по началу я подумал что проблема из-за него (может не освобождает память после загрузки текстуры, мало ли...). Ещё один вариант нашёл **AndroidJNI.DeleteLocalRef(cObj.GetNativeTexturePtr())**, так же попробовал вручную уничтожать WWW через **Destroy(cObj)**, но это не помогало.

**Решение:**
    Так как перед этим была небольшая ошибка на сервера она скрыла этот краш, в добавок ко всему сильно сбивало то, что в эдиторе всё работало как часы, но потом я понял что проблема в том, что загружать теперь нужно больше картинок и следовательно отдебажив, я понял что их число возросло до 618. Тут я и понял, что проблема в создании одновременно такого количества "потоков" при внезапно появившемся ограничении в 512 на андроид. Видимо в юнити создание псеводопотоков делается через локальные переменные, что очень сбивает с правильного направления мыслей. Решением было создать **Queue< IEnumerator >** которая бы контролировала количество одновременных корутин. Вместе с переменными **лимита_корутин** и **текущего_кол_корутин** проблема решается в два счёта.Так как было уже позно - быстро накидал в Update, но так делать не рекомендую, лучше сделать через корутину. В моменте, где создаём потоки просто добавляем проверку на лимит - если превышено отправляем в Очередь, если нет - на выполнение.В конце выполнения не забудьте со счётчика тек_кол_корутин вычесть завершившийся поток.

```
    public static int coroutines_limit=200;
    public int coroutines_count;

    public Queue<IEnumerator> jobs = new Queue<IEnumerator>(coroutines_limit);
///


    void Update()
    {     

        if (coroutines_limit>coroutines_count&&jobs.Count>0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(jobs.Peek());
            jobs.Dequeue();
            coroutines_count++;
        }        
    }
```

[image: mireport]

Comment: var ienumerator = YourIEnumerator;  if (coroutines_count<coroutines_limit)
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(ienumerator);
                        coroutines_count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jobs.Enqueue( ienumerator);
                    }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [`ask the same question on StackOverflow in English`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.